# Swift no option to add an Ob-C bridging header file under Build Options

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have added some Objective C files to my Swift project using Cocoapods.  I created a Bridging-Header.h file using File->New->File IOS Source Header File.  It is in the project.  See screen shot with project files on left.  I now need to add that file to the Project Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Code Generation.

The problem is (see screen shot) that the option to add the Bridge file does not exist!!! ???  I cannot find a reference to a problem like this anywhere on the web, cocoapods or apple. Can anyone suggest a way to get the option to add the bridging file appear in the Build Settings

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to click on "ALL" tab. If you take a look to your picture, you're on "Basic", switching to "ALL" should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks.  That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a command-f find that's filtering stuff from your view there. All I see is your optimization level stuff.

You should also probably put the bridging header at the app target level rather than at the project level.